# UV Mapping is not apply uv grid texture to my face model

Tags: modeling

So now as it says in the title the my model in uv map the grid does did not apply to my character face model.[image]

If anyone can explain what is happening i would be delighted OH! also it turns out its only the face model that has this issue for the others it there perfectly fine.

Here's a the downloadable blender file.
http://www.mediafire.com/folder/bq64qo9bblxq4qf,3xr57eh55ac4xza,id9am3km23aj24v,bmbnna48s4n72q3/shared

Comment: there are 4 different files, which one do you want us to download? Also, have you created a material with the grid as Image Texture?

Comment: sorry i believe it was a untitled 2

Comment: have you followed a tutorial like this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y27pCgJxLvg , in Cycles Render (your are in Blender Render though) you need to create a material with your Texture Grid plugged into a Diffuse and plug the Diffuse into an Output, otherwise you won't see the grid on your mesh